# Properly Clearing a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

So I'm trying to check the RGB values of a picture in my gallery, here is how my code works: I get the image and set it on my iv_image variable, then when I click on the image, it will get the values of RGB around the area I clicked. The problem is when I change the image, the bitmap value doesnt change and remains te values of the previous image.

Here is my code:

```
 iv_image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(!(iv_image.getDrawable() == null)){
                int touchX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                int touchY = (int) motionEvent.getY();

                iv_image.buildDrawingCache();

                Bitmap bitmap = iv_image.getDrawingCache();
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
                /*
                final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
                ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
                        finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                cicleOverlay.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
                c
                icleOverlay.getLayoutParams().height = 150;

                */

                int valorMinimoR = 0, valorMaximoR = 0, valorMinimoG = 0,
                        valorMaximoG = 0, valorMinimoB = 0, valorMaximoB = 0;
                for (int i=-50; i < 50; i++){
                    for (int x=-50; x < 50; x++) {
                        if ((touchX) > 0 && (touchY) > 0 && (touchX) < bitmap.getWidth() && (touchY) < bitmap.getHeight()) {
                            int pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(touchX + i, touchY + x);
                            int A = Color.alpha(pixelColor);
                            int R = Color.red(pixelColor);
                            int G = Color.green(pixelColor);
                            int B = Color.blue(pixelColor);

                            if (mediaB == 0 && mediaG == 0 && mediaR == 0) {
                                mediaR = R;
                                mediaG = G;
                                mediaB = B;
                            }

                            if (valorMinimoR > R || valorMinimoR == 0)
                                valorMinimoR = R;
                            if (valorMaximoR < R)
                                valorMaximoR = R;

                            if (valorMinimoG > G || valorMinimoG == 0)
                                valorMinimoG = G;
                            if (valorMaximoG < G)
                                valorMaximoG = G;

                            if (valorMinimoB > B || valorMinimoB == 0)
                                valorMinimoB = B;
                            if (valorMaximoB < B)
                                valorMaximoB = B;

                            mediaR = (mediaR + R) / 2;
                            mediaG = (mediaG + G) / 2;
                            mediaB = (mediaB + B) / 2;

                            if (i == 0 && x == 0) {
                                r = R;
                                g = G;
                                b = B;
                            }
                            if (i >= 49 && x >= 49) {
                                tv_color.setText("\nVermelho: " + r + "\nVerde: " + g + "\nAzul: " + b +
                                        "\nMedia Vermelho: " + mediaR + "\nMedia Verde: " + mediaG + "\nMedia Azul: " + mediaB +
                                        "\nMenor/Maior Vermelho: " + valorMinimoR + "/" + valorMaximoR + "\nMenor/Maior Verde: " +
                                        valorMinimoG + "/" + valorMaximoG + "\nMenor/Maior Azul: " + valorMinimoB + "/" + valorMaximoB);

                                int rr = math.round(mediaR);
                                int gg = math.round(mediaG);
                                int bb = math.round(mediaB);
                                //iv_color.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(rr, gg, bb));
                                iv_color.setBackground(d);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mediaR = 0;
            mediaG = 0;
            mediaB = 0;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I tried to use  bitmap.recycle() and bitmap = null to reset bitmap values, but when I do, the program crashes, anyone have any ideas on how to solve it?

Edit 1: The part where I set the modified Image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        iv_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
```

Comment: You have to set the modified image in to the View

Comment: Ill edit the part where I set the modified image. Even though I have already done it, i might have used the wrong method.

Comment: The image does change in my view, and I from what I saw lately, the bitmap cannot ever be changed.

Comment: Only mutable bitmaps can be changed